# Method for sorting an evaluated Queryset (Django)

Tags: python, django

I have the following function and test:

```
def create_question(days, question_text="Empty"):
    time = timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=days)
    return Question.objects.create(question_text = question_text, pub_date=time) 

def test_two_past_questions(self):
    """
    The questions index page may display multiple questions.
    """
    create_question(question_text="Past question 1.", days=-30)
    create_question(question_text="Past question 2.", days=-5)
    response = self.client.get(reverse('polls:index'))
    self.assertQuerysetEqual(
        response.context['latest_question_list'].order_by('-pub_date'),
        ['<Question: Past question 1.>', '<Question: Past question 2.>'],
    )
```

This generates the following error:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
....F...
======================================================================
FAIL: test_two_past_questions (polls.tests.QuestionIndexViewTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/.local/share/virtualenvs/django/mysite/polls/tests.py", line 74, in test_two_past_questions
    latest_question_list.order_by('-pub_date')
  File 
"/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/.local/share/virtualenvs/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 962, in order_by
    "Cannot reorder a query once a slice has been taken."
AssertionError: Cannot reorder a query once a slice has been taken.
```

To my understanding, it generates an error because the `Queryset` is already evaluated and `order_by` is only for reordering in the database.

Without the failed sorting attepmpt, my test is failing because the objects are in wrong order:

```
FAIL: test_two_past_questions (polls.tests.QuestionIndexViewTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/.local/share/virtualenvs/django/mysite/polls/tests.py", line 77, in test_two_past_questions
    ['<Question: Past question 1.>', '<Question: Past question 2.>'],
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/.local/share/virtualenvs/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 972, in assertQuerysetEqual
    return self.assertEqual(list(items), values, msg=msg)
AssertionError: Lists differ: ['<Question: Past question 2.>', '<Question: Past question 1.>'] != ['<Question: Past question 1.>', '<Question: Past question 2.>']

First differing element 0:
'<Question: Past question 2.>'
'<Question: Past question 1.>'

- ['<Question: Past question 2.>', '<Question: Past question 1.>']
?                            ^                               ^

+ ['<Question: Past question 1.>', '<Question: Past question 2.>']
?                            ^                               ^
```

I want to ensure they are in the right order by sorting them by their `pub_date`. Is there a way of sorting a Queryset object like you would sort a normal list?